# Button component with customizable background image

Tags: html, css, reactjs, button, background-image

I'm building a reusable Button component in React whose background image is an image of a button (e.g. PNG export from Figma) and is customizable.

My current implementation is as follows -

**Button.js**

```
const Button = ({ url }) => {
    const inlineStyle = {
        backgroundImage: `url(${url})`
    }

    return (
        <button
            type='submit'
            style={inlineStyle}
            className='button'
        />
    )
}
```

**Button.css**

```
.button {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 30px 0;

    border: none;

    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    cursor: pointer;
}
```

But, the problem is this doesn't support all kind of button sizes. If a button is really wide and short in height, I'll have to readjust it again with another `className` like so -

```
const Button = ({ url, modifierClass }) => {
    const inlineStyle = {
        backgroundImage: `url(${url})`
    }

    return (
        <button
            type='submit'
            style={inlineStyle}
            className={`button ${modifierClass}`}
        />
    )
}
```

```
.modifier {
    max-width: 300px;
}
```

If it is a narrow button -

```
.modifier {
    max-width: 140px;
}
```

My question is how do I code the Button component and its CSS so that it supports all kind of background image button shape; narrow, wide or tall on a fixed size?

Comment: What about using `backgorund-size: cover`?
*Resize the background image to cover the entire container, even if it has to stretch the image or cut a little bit off one of the edges*

Comment: @AliBahaari Since I had written `width: 100%; padding: 30px 0;`, it will stretch and the image as a whole won't get displayed. If I remove those, the button disappears.

Comment: Provide a sandbox.

Comment: @AliBahaari I use `min-height` instead of `padding` here. Button is basically gone if I remove those. I think I'll just have to set a fixed size for all button. My question sounds stupid, now that I think about it, haha.

[codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-cannon-5y5dll](https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-cannon-5y5dll)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [Ali Bahaari's help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73665502/7580064) I figured out I can use `max-width` to control the `Button`'s size.

I can accept `size` as prop and put it as `max-width` in inline style,

```
const Button = ({ url, size }) => {
    const inlineStyle = {
        backgroundImage: `url(${url})`,
        maxWidth: size
    }

    return (
        <button
            type='submit'
            style={inlineStyle}
            className='button'
        />
    )
}
```

and use the component like `<Button size='100px' />`.

This won't support responsiveness as inline style doesn't support media queries. If adjusting size per screen is needed, I'll just have to use the way in my question.

Answer (score 1):

I think I got what are you looking for. Change `background-size: 'contain'` to `background-size: 'cover'` and give it `max-width: 100px` (`100px` for example) and by using `padding`, `height`, `min-height` or etc., you get the same result and background doesn't need to be readjusted.

```css
.ButtonComponent {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100px; /* Max width for the button */
  padding: 30px 0; /* `min-height` / `height` */
  border: none;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-size: cover; /* Change `contain` to `cover` */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
}
```

Comment: I used `background-size: contain` so that the whole button image is shown as background. Using `cover` makes the image cropped on a fixed size. 

But, your answer makes me realize I can use `max-width` as a dynamic customizable style for the component. 

Like `<Button size='100px' />` where `size` prop is `max-width`.